# Where to put traversing graph query in DDD while avoiding doing hundreds of smaller ones?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

So I've been trying to make a bit of DDD at the project I work on, but I'm facing the problem I mention in the title.
We have the `Entity.php` generated by the Symfony console, with the Doctrine annotations in there (I know it is not how it should be made), and the corresponding `EntityRepository.php`.

The applicable object graph is:
`Post` entity contains a `Messages` collection, which in turn have a `ReadMessages`collection because we need to know by whom has it been read. To know whether a `Post` has been read, we want to left join `Messages` with `ReadMessages` filtering by the user we need, and if there are any blank `ReadMessages`, we'll know it has not been read.

If we use a method in the `Post` entity to iterate over all `Messages` and all `ReadMessages` for each of those, Doctrine will be making lots of queries unless we configure the associations as *Eager*, which we don't want to because then it will be retrieving the associations all the times we ask for a `Post`; the ideal way would be to use a DQL query that loads the joined entities, but since there is no way to access the repository from the entity (apart from injecting one in the other -which I don't even know if is possible-), I think the only option left is to use a Symfony2 service that gets Doctrine injected. The thing is that I don't really like having to add another piece just as a helper.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What if you would filter your collection using criteria (`Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria`)? I think this might solve your problem. You can read on how to do this in detail [in the Doctrine2 documentation in 8.8](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).

It is as simple as you define your `Criteria` as *where message is read* and then you get the filtered result as follows:

```
/**
  * Get all read messages
  *
  * @return Collection
  */
public function getReadMessages(){
    $isReadCriteria = //... define criteria
    $messages = $this->getMessages();
    $readMessages = $messages->matching($isReadCriteria);
    return $readMessages;
}
```

Comment: Actually I discovered the `Criteria` API a few minutes after posting the question here; I also thought that could be what I was looking for, but I'm not fully convinced about it yet.  Where would I add that method you mention? In the `ReadMessages` entity, in `Messages`, or in `Post`?

Comment: Inside `Post`. So you define relationship between messages and post and add this extra `getReadMessages` method to the `Post` entity.

Comment: But according to [this article](http://mnapoli.fr/collection-interface-and-database-abstraction/), that's not allowed: _you cannot filter on associations of objects inside the collection, i.e. JOIN (which is pretty common)_

Comment: *You cannot filter on associations of objects* means in this case that you cannot filter on associations with `Message`, only on properties of message. In your case (if I understood it correctly) the `isRead` flag is a property of message, so using `Criteria` shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: But hey, writing a repository query is always more flexible, but from your question it seemed like that was not what you wanted...

Comment: There isn't a flag `isRead` on `Messages`, there are `ReadMessages` because we have to link a `Message` with somebody that read it. Because of this, `ReadMessages` is a collection of `Messages`. Also, I can't do it in the repository because I need a way  in the view to determine whether the current `Post` is read.